# USB number pad won't work

Tags: usb, hardware

Last week I recycled my fiance's 2011 Macbook Pro 13.3 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto it. I need a numerical number pad for work so I picked up [this from Office Depot](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/396137/iHome-USB-20-Numeric-Keypad-Silver/?cm_mmc=PLA-_-Google-_-Computer_Tablet_Accessories-_-396137-VQ6-42102212396-VQ16c-VQ17-pla-VQ18-online-VQ19-396137-VQ20-18283950120-VQ21-&gclid=CjwKEAjwm-aqBRD39YPqhbzthzYSJACFj-AtjXe6Pn-Q0BAbbmtBcAVtU2rjYwnCuonlSnH_0XlPARoCB-bw_wcB). When I run lsusb it shows up as

`Bus 001 Device 013: ID 05a4:8003 Ortek Technology, Inc.`

When I run evtest I can see it in two different places

```
$ sudo evtest
[sudo] password for : 
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event3:  Power Button
/dev/input/event4:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event5:  Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
/dev/input/event6:  FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
/dev/input/event7:  Keypad USB Keypad     
/dev/input/event8:  applesmc
/dev/input/event9:  HDA Intel PCH Line
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event11: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event13: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event14: bcm5974
/dev/input/event15: Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver
/dev/input/event16: Keypad USB Keypad     
Select the device event number [0-16]:
```

The two options that disappear after unplugging the device are 7 and 16. After selecting option 7 I get this message

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x5a4 product 0x8003 version 0x110
Input device name: "Keypad USB Keypad     "
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 121 (KEY_KPCOMMA)
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 129 (KEY_AGAIN)
    Event code 130 (KEY_PROPS)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 132 (KEY_FRONT)
    Event code 133 (KEY_COPY)
    Event code 134 (KEY_OPEN)
    Event code 135 (KEY_PASTE)
    Event code 136 (KEY_FIND)
    Event code 137 (KEY_CUT)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 187 (KEY_F17)
    Event code 188 (KEY_F18)
    Event code 189 (KEY_F19)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 194 (KEY_F24)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML)
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL)
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL)
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE)
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA)
Properties:
  Property type 20 (EV_REP)
    Property code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Property code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

Option 16 will output this

```
    Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x5a4 product 0x8003 version 0x110
Input device name: "Keypad USB Keypad     "
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 143 (KEY_WAKEUP)
    Event code 144 (KEY_FILE)
    Event code 155 (KEY_MAIL)
    Event code 156 (KEY_BOOKMARKS)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 171 (KEY_CONFIG)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 173 (KEY_REFRESH)
    Event code 217 (KEY_SEARCH)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE)
    Event code 275 (BTN_SIDE)
    Event code 276 (BTN_EXTRA)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
    Event code 8 (REL_WHEEL)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 8 (LED_MISC)
    Event code 9 (?)
    Event code 10 (?)
    Event code 11 (?)
    Event code 12 (?)
    Event code 13 (?)
    Event code 14 (?)
    Event code 15 (?)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

No button pressing of the keypad will register in the terminal.

Is it possible for me to get this working or do I need to buy one that isn't specifically for OSX?

Comment: Sorry Tim, I tried editing it but you beat me to it.

Comment: Sokay. Use Ctrl+K to format code, if you select multi line code it will auto format. If you select a single line it will put `` around it, or you can self type ``.